# Program won't start through bat file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a program called `program.exe`

It's located in the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft\program.exe
```

I want to start it through a bat file but failed to do so.

Everything works when I do this in cmd:

```
cmd> cd C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft\
cmd> program.exe
// program is running
```

I tried to do it in a bat file using these combinations:

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft\program.exe"
Start /d "" "C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft" "program.exe"
Start /d /w "" "C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft" "program.exe"
```

But failed everytime.

What's wrong with my file?

Comment: What failures did you get?

Comment: "unable to read the configuration file"

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure it's not a permission issue? Can you reproduce the issue with a different directory?

Comment: It works with other programs. And I have discovered that the only way it works in cmd is by firstly going to the path `(prog files\comp\soft)` and then the `program.exe`. How could I implement this (multiple lines in cmd) in my batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
cd "c:\Program Files\Comp\Soft"
start "" program.exe
```

Comment: Is this your exe or a third party?

Comment: third party. could it be the reason of the developers you think?

Comment: I'm wondering if they are depending on the current directory for some thing (just a wild guess though)

Comment: yea I have no idea tbh but it worked! Thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Yout `start` syntax is wrong, you need to specify the working directory immediately after the `/D` option:

```
Start "" /D "C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft" "program.exe"
```

Or:

```
Start "" /D "C:\Program Files\Comp\Soft" /WAIT "program.exe"
```